EASA Equivalent of CAA CAP 697 and CAP 698 Training Documents
I am wondering if by now there are EASA-issued documents containing the same information as the CAA examinations training documents CAP 697 ("Flight Planning Manual") and CAP 698 ("Aeroplane Performance Manual").
I did find that the EASA Easy Access Rules for Aircrew in AMC1 FCL.310; FCL.515(b); FCL.615(b); FCL.835(d) Theoretical knowledge examinations still mention that:

Excerpts from any aircraft manuals including but not limited to CAP 696, 697 and 698 for aeroplanes, and CAP 758 for helicopters may be used in training. Where questions refer to excerpts from aircraft manuals, the associated aircraft data will be provided in the examinations.

However, I could not find any equivalent training documents. Is the information spread out over multiple Easy Access rules documents?

CAP documents also referenced in Annex II to ED Decision 2016/008/R, and no alternative suggested.
